# Is it possible to create an empty ClassLoader?

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to create a new ClassLoader instance, which contains absolutely no classes at the beginning. It shouldn't have a single class available. Not even the java.lang classes. I want to be able to load every class manually for my own location. ( With an overriden defineClass method )

The problem is that every attempt I make into this fails. Any new made ClassLoader contains all classes in the CLASSPATH variable.

Now is my question:
Is it possible to create an empty ClassLoader? ( No classes - especially from the CLASSPATH - should be loaded )

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not possible.

When you define a classloader (create it on your own), you need to define it's parent classloader.
When you don't define one, the bootstrap classloader is the default.

The need of a parent classloader is a security concern. **The *java.lang* classes** come from the **bootstrap** classloader.

---

Here a more deep explanation from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader:

> Each Java class must be loaded by a class loader.[2] Furthermore, Java
>   programs may make use of external libraries (that is, libraries
>   written and provided by someone other than the author of the program)
>   or they may be composed, at least in part, of a number of libraries.
>
> When the JVM is started, three class loaders are used:[3][4]
>
> Bootstrap class loader
>
> Extensions class loader
>
> System class loader
>
> The bootstrap class loader loads the core Java libraries[5] located in the
>   /jre/lib directory. This class loader, which is part of the
>   core JVM, is written in native code.
>
> The extensions class loader loads the code in the extensions
>   directories (/jre/lib/ext,[6] or any other directory
>   specified by the java.ext.dirs system property). It is implemented by
>   the sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader class.
>
> The system class loader loads code found on java.class.path, which
>   maps to the CLASSPATH environment variable. This is implemented by the
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader class.

Comment: +1 You need standard classes like Object, String etc. Without these your ClassLoader cannot function.

Comment: I've already been looking into the sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader. It appears to be an instance of the URLClassLoader calling its constructor: `super( getExtURLs(dirs), null, factory );` where "null" is the parent ClassLoader. It appears I can't get further than replacing the Extensions class loader. It seems there indeed is no way to replace the bootstrap classloader.

Comment: Correct @Dennis. When you use "null" it gets the default, that would be the bootstrap classloader. This classloader loads all java.lang classes.